# Wilsonian effective action and dimensional regularization

Tags: renormalization, regularization, effective-field-theory, dimensional-regularization

In the Wilsonian approach to QFTs, QFTs are treated as effective field theories which are reliable at some UV cut-off $\Lambda_{eff}$, We then integrated out high energy modes and see how couplings change.

At the end where we are working with IR effective action, low energy momentum mode in loop integrals should be restricted to $\Lambda_c$, where we have integrated out high energy modes between $\Lambda_c<k<\Lambda_{eff}$.

As an example, consider a scalar theory as follows

\begin{equation} 
\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{L}_{\mathcal{D<4}}+\frac{c_6}{\Lambda^2_{eff}}\frac{1}{6!}\phi^6
\end{equation}

and the mass correction of the above irrelevant operator is easy to compute and the contribution is as follows [1]

\begin{equation} 
\mathcal{M}=-\frac{c_6}{2\Lambda^2_{eff}}\int\frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{1}{k^2-m^2_{\phi}}\sim-\frac{c_6}{2\Lambda^2_{eff}}\frac{\Lambda_c^2}{16\pi^2}
\end{equation}

But it is argued that this approach is not satisfiable [1,2,3], because there are other operators with the same effects, for example $\phi^2(\partial_{\mu}\phi)^2$ which contributes as follows :
\begin{equation} 
\mathcal{M}=-\frac{c_8}{2\Lambda^2_{eff}}\int\frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{k^2}{k^2-m^2_{\phi}}\sim-\frac{c_8}{\Lambda^4_{eff}}\frac{\Lambda_c^4}{16\pi^2}
\end{equation}
and the corrections of the different irrelevant operators are of the same order if $\Lambda\sim\Lambda_c$, and EFT expansion in power of $\frac{1}{\Lambda_{eff}}$ break down [1]. So we need to imply another scheme where $\Lambda_c$ is not explicitly at calculations. By dimensional regularization we have

\begin{equation} 
I=\mu^{2\epsilon}\int\frac{d^Dk}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{1}{k^2-m^2_{\phi}}=\frac{i}{16\pi^2}(\frac{1}{\epsilon}-\gamma+log(\frac{4\pi^2\mu^2}{m^2_{\phi}}))
\end{equation}

In $\overline{MS}$-scheme the correction to the mass will be as follows :

\begin{equation} 
\frac{\delta m}{m}\sim c_6\frac{m_{\phi}^2}{\Lambda^2_{eff}}log(\frac{\mu^2}{m^2_{\phi}})
\end{equation}

**My question** dimensional regularization is contradictory to me, It seems that it is integrated over all momentum range $-\infty<k<\infty$ (as the integral is obviously divergent in $\epsilon\to 0$ limit) and this violate Wilsonian perspective that effective field theories are reliable up to some cut-off and we have to integrate in loop integrals up to $\Lambda_c$.

References:

1. Aneesh V. Manohar, Introduction to Effective Field Theories, (https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.05863) p. 31-36
2. David B. Kaplan, *Effective Field Theories,*
   [arXiv:nucl-th/9506035](https://arxiv.org/abs/nucl-th/9506035); p. 15-18.
3. Sourendu Gupta, [*Wilsonian Renormalization and Effective Field
   Theories*](https://theory.tifr.res.in/%7Esgupta/courses/serc14/), [lecture
   2](https://theory.tifr.res.in/%7Esgupta/courses/serc14/lec2.pdf);  p. 18-22.